# Two rows are inserted into DB table instead of one

Tags: mysql, angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a full stack java application using Angular as frontend, spring boot as REST API and MySQL as the DB. I'm doing CRUD operation on a student object. Read, Update and Delete operations are working perfectly but when I'm trying to create a new student two records are inserted into DB with identical details(except student_id which is unique) instead of one. I have created a new student form to create a new student and the same form is used to update an existing student also.

[image]

On clicking Save button in the form it goes to the following method:

```
save(){
    if(this.id == -1) { 
      this.studentService.createStudent(this.student)
          .subscribe (
            data => {
              console.log(data)
              this.router.navigate(['students'])
            }
          )
    } else {
      this.studentService.updateStudent(this.id, this.student)
          .subscribe (
            data => {
              console.log(data)
              this.router.navigate(['students'])
            }
          )
    }
  }
```

I have debugged and found that this method is invoked twice and studentService.createStudent is called twice. I have no clue why this is happening. The same method is used for Update operation also but at that time it is invoked only once.

Comment: You need to show the form code. How is the `save()` function invoked?

Comment: Add the html code too

Answer (score 0):

Add a break; or return; after the data is inserted to the database so it's impossible for the method to be called twice.

Comment: put breakpoints in your code where something will execute something and check the values and how your code will run.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this problem. Create a flag studentUpdated in the component file to store the status if the student is already inserted into the DB table:

```
studentUpdated: Boolean
```

Then create a new student only if the flag is false otherwise it will only update the existing details of the student. Updated save method is as follows:

```
save(){
    if(this.studentUpdated===false){
    if(this.id == -1) { 
      this.studentService.createStudent(this.student)
          .subscribe (
            data => {
              console.log(data)
              this.router.navigate(['students'])
            }
          )
          this.studentUpdated=true;          
    } else {
      this.studentService.updateStudent(this.id, this.student)
          .subscribe (
            data => {
              console.log(data)
              this.router.navigate(['students'])
            }
          )
    }
    this.studentUpdated=true;    
  }
  }
```